# Prevent users to view items that other users created and preserve alert functionality

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, permissions

I want to prevent users to view items that other users created, both in lists and in forms (Dispform, Editform).

I can not use the setting "Read items that were created by the user" in List Settings\Advanced Settings\Read access, because this option prevents the users to set alerts on lists and items. When i try to add an alert i get the following error messages:

"You cannot create alerts for lists for which users can only read their own items." and
"You cannot create alerts for lists for which users can only read their own items."

I can not use an eventReceiver to implement custom code for filtering, because there is none for ItemOpened or ItemOpening events.

And i do not want to use Item Level Permissions due to performance and maintainability reasons.

I there any other way to accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set the filter on the list view, like this
[image]
Having done that set the modified view as default and delete all others views, as administrator create a new view but as Personal View, so only you can see it.

And for disable the alerts, follow this [link](http://blogs.c5insight.com/Home/tabid/40/entryid/375/Disable-SharePoint-Alerts-on-a-Specific-List.aspx)

None of this solutions are 100% efficient if the user are not set in groups

Good louck with that.